# What? jQuery Why? I can't get this icon to disappear

Tags: jquery, drupal

[Page in Question](http://%20http://ahs.alliantdev.armedianet.com/careers)

I wrote four of these as there are 8 icons total. Idea is simple. Hover over icon, div shows.

I have it working except for three problems
1.) It's jumpy
2.) The first Medical benefits stays way too long
3.) I wrote 4 files when only one is needed.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#medical-icon").hover(
        function() {
            console.log($("#medical-benefits").fadeIn());
            $("#medical-benefits").fadeIn();
        },
        function() {
            $("#medical-benefits").fadeOut();
        }
    );

    $("#heart-icon").hover(
        function() {
                 $("#wellness-benefits").fadeIn();

        },
        function() {
            $("#wellness-benefits").fadeOut();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: .stop didn't change anything.sadly

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?, create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: i included a link to my page

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I ended up using CSS to do this. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBLZx/) The strange this is this only works if the divs are all under the SAME div.

Comment: _"The strange this is this only works if the divs are all under the SAME div."_ ? Not certain interpret this portion of comment correctly ? Does http://jsfiddle.net/MBLZx/ resolve Question ?